# anchor tag not working inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a navbar and following bootstrap styling. My anchor tag is not working on the drop-down nav menus. I tried many examples of similar problems people were having. like z-index, block element, floating. None of those seems to work in my case. Not sure whats going on.Below is the partial code i am working with. I have a jquery function that I use to detect the mouse hover so I can drop the menu and other things. there i do have event prevent default. But removing that doesnt seem to do anything either

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(' .dropdown-content a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(' .dropdown-content a').removeClass('active1');
    $(this).closest(' .dropdown li').find("a:eq(0)").addClass('active1');
    $(this).closest(' .top-nav li').find("a:eq(0)").addClass('dropbtn');
    $(this).addClass('active1');
  });

  

});
```

```css
.navbar-inverse{background-color:#004f8e!important; border-color: #004f8e!important; border-radius:0px!important; border-top: 6px solid #57be17!important;}
.top-nav li a{color:white!important;}
.top-nav li a i{    font-size: 9px; vertical-align: middle;margin-top: -3px; margin-right: 12px;}
.dropbtn {color: white; padding: 16px; font-size: 16px;border: none;cursor: pointer;}
.dropdown { position: relative; display: inline-block;}
.dropdown-content { display: none; position: absolute; background-color: #f9f9f9;min-width: 190px; box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); z-index: 5;}
.dropdown-content a {color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block; z-index: 15;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { display: block;}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn { text-decoration:none; background-color:#57be17;}
.active1{background:#57be17;}
a{ text-decoration:none!important;}
```

```html
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav top-nav pull-right">
     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> About Us</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Providers</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Payors</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Employers</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>


     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Patients</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Did you include the Jquery js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `e.preventDefault();`  from the anchor `click` call. It stops the default action of an element from happening. In case of link, it stops the link from opening the URL. Moreover, most of your links do not have a href specified. Where  will the anchor tag navigate to?

Comment: wow, that fixed it. I thought that didn't work. I did remove that once. it's working like a charm now. I think my hot reload was messed up. Appreciate it bro

Answer (score 0):

You need to include JQuery. I adjusted the following snippet so you could see the outline of the a tag to hover over.

If you're working on a JQuery project and you see the phrase `$ is undefined` it means that the JQuery library either hasn't been included, has been overwritten, or somewhere in the code you've used `JQuery.noConflict()` - which allows you to use JQuery objects by using `JQuery` instead of `$`. More often than not it's because it wasn't included.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(' .dropdown-content a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(' .dropdown-content a').removeClass('active1');
    $(this).closest(' .dropdown li').find("a:eq(0)").addClass('active1');
    $(this).closest(' .top-nav li').find("a:eq(0)").addClass('dropbtn');
    $(this).addClass('active1');
  });

  

});
```

```css
.navbar-inverse{background-color:#004f8e!important; border-color: #004f8e!important; border-radius:0px!important; border-top: 6px solid #57be17!important;}
.top-nav li a{color:white!important;}
.top-nav li a i{    font-size: 9px; vertical-align: middle;margin-top: -3px; margin-right: 12px;}
.dropbtn {color: white; padding: 16px; font-size: 16px;border: none;cursor: pointer;}
.dropdown { position: relative; display: inline-block;}
.dropdown-content { display: none; position: absolute; background-color: #f9f9f9;min-width: 190px; box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); z-index: 5;}
.dropdown-content a {color: black;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block; z-index: 15;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { display: block;}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn { text-decoration:none; background-color:#57be17;}
.active1{background:#57be17;}
a{ text-decoration:none!important; border: 1px black solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav top-nav pull-right">
     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> About Us</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Providers</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Payors</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Employers</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>


     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Patients</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Action</a>
       <a href="#">Another action</a>
       <a href="#">Something else here</a>
       <a href="#">Separated link</a>
       <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be because jQuery is being sourced after the DOM is ready.  Try wrapping your jQuery code in a setTimeout(function () {   }, 3000)  to get it to wait 3 seconds and see if jQuery becomes visible, if not visible at DOM ready.